# Relation between roughness of a p-n junction and interatomic spacing

Tags: semiconductor-physics, crystals

> Question:Can we take one slab of p-type semiconductor and physically join it to another n-type semiconductor to get p-n junction?

> Answer:No! Any slab, howsoever flat, will have roughness much
> larger than the inter-atomic crystal spacing (~2 to 3 Å) and hence
> continuous contact at the atomic level will not be possible. The junction
> will behave as a discontinuity for the flowing charge carriers -[From](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph206.pdf) pg,479

And here is the intended method for making p-n junctions:

> Consider a thin p-type silicon (p-Si) semiconductor wafer. By adding
> precisely a small quantity of pentavelent impurity, part of the p-Si wafer
> can be converted into n-Si.

I'm a bit confused as to how the 'roughness' of the slab's surface relates to the interatomic spacing. How exactly do you measure the roughness in terms of interatomic crystal spacing?

I understood the second part with the idea that we need continous overlap of orbitals for creation of bonds.

Comment: Physically placing one piece of copper against another is not the same as one continuous copper piece either, and the conductivity across that gap shows it. I suspect that appropriately treated atomically smooth surface in UHV could be placed together and annealed to create a single crystal. A heavily defected interface will not perform like a junction.

Comment: You seems to have multiple unrelated questions. Are you asking the question in the title or are you asking about measuring surface roughness?

Answer (score 1):

"How exactly do you measure the roughness in terms of interatomic crystal spacing?"

Perhaps this image will help. It shows the surface of a silicon wafer:

[image: Silicon surface]

([Taken from NIST](https://www.nist.gov/image/8nmpng).)

You can see a series of plateaus and steps. Each of these plateaus is a crystal plane, and each step between them has a height equal to the interatomic crystal spacing. So, if you have a relatively nice crystal, the roughness is in discrete steps with a height of the interatomic crystal spacing. If you have amorphous silicon instead of crystalline silicon, then all bets are off because there are no nice steps.